# RDF/XML for apache jena format using java

Tags: java, rdf, jena

The error I get when I change `list1[0]` to `list1[1]`:

[image]

I am doing a progam that prints from a file using RDF model in java, I wanted to let the object to be as a Sting but i couldn’t find a way for it, I tried  to make by using the  2-d array to let it reads from the file and print the data into the output screen. However, it doesn't work and I couldn't figure out the reason.

Here is my code:

```
String synonyms =null;

try {
        File file1 = new File("Data/9687.txt");
        FileReader fileReader1 = new FileReader(file1);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader1 = new BufferedReader(fileReader1);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line1;
        System.out.println("Proteins & Synonyms:");
        while ((bufferedReader1.readLine()) != null) {
                line1 = bufferedReader1.readLine();
                String[] list1 = line1.split(“/t”)
                synonyms=model1.expandPrefix(list1[0]);
                proteinG.addProperty(hasSynonyms,synonyms);
```

And here is the OUTPUT message shown:

```
<https://Bio2cv.net/ENSP000003488> <hasSynonyms> "ENSP000003488” .
```

The output for the resource is the same as the string.

Comment: How should your desired output look like?

Comment: <https://Bio2cv.net/9606.ENSP00000348838> <hasSynonyms> "the synonym name" .    i want the output to be like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the synonym name in the **second column** of the input file?
If so, you are using bad index `0` here:

```
            synonyms=model1.expandPrefix(list1[0]);
```

Change it to `1` and also remove the `model1.expandPrefix()` call if you want a plain string literal:

```
            synonyms=list1[1];
```

---

For skipping invalid lines (without tab character) change the code after the `split()` call. Check the length of the `list1` array:

```
            String[] list1 = line1.split("\t");
            if (list1.length < 2) continue;
```

---

You are also reading two lines form the input instead of one.

Change this code:

```
    while ((bufferedReader1.readLine()) != null) {
            line1 = bufferedReader1.readLine();
```

to this:

```
    while ((line1 = bufferedReader1.readLine()) != null) {
```

Comment: i did it before, and the same didn't work. i guess what i did wrong is in this syntax itself --> {synonyms=model1.expandPrefix(list1[1])}, and i couldn't figure out the correct one

Comment: @Ghas I would also remove the `model1.expandPrefix()` call, see my edit...

Comment: but when i change the list1[0]; to list1[1] it shows an error.

Comment: @Ghas What error? Can you post the full message and stack trace?

Comment: @Ghas ok I see it: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` - it means that there is a line in the input where there is no tab (`\t`) character. You have to remove it or skip it in your code - I will make another edit in my answer...

Comment: I have a question, have you done any RDF graphs before?

Comment: now i am doing one, but i am confused. i wrote the RDF by hands, and i am not sure if i done it right!

Comment: Just test it - loud it to some RDF store e.g. jena fuseki a you will see if it's correct.

Comment: can you give me some instructions in how to use it

Comment: For example at the end of this video: https://youtu.be/8F3TWJvgmBU You can see how to load a RDF file to fuseki and ask some SPARQL query against the data...

Comment: ok thank you. 
i have another question, when printing the RDF in java, i want to print it using RDF/XML, but i shows an error. do you know any possible solution for it

Comment: I wold need to see the error message... You can post another question to stack overflow...

Comment: i reached the limits for asking questions

Comment: Can you post to this chat room? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176635/apache-jena

Comment: unfortunately no